# How to pipe an echo command through grep when adding?

Tags: linux, shell-script

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsHe2.jpg

Hello all,

Im trying to write a script that will add any input numbers and return the sum. I have this part, here's the code:

```
    sum=0
    for number in "$@";
    do ((sum += number))
    done
    echo $sum
```

Now I need it to do the rest that is attached in the image, but we only learned if statements and for loops two days ago, and I'm having trouble getting through this. I've tried all combinations I could think of, and I just end up getting frustrating errors.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text in the image. It's too hard to read on my device.

Comment: What have you tried and what errors do you get? Please include this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use awk this has been answered in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line

You did not say what shell you are using but it looks like sh or bash.  What you have is correct if it is put in a script (but will not work at the command line).  I put your code in a file named test.sh and then executed it as:

sh test.sh 10 20 30

and it printed out the correct value of 60